# Black-Scholes model with a derivative with payoff $S_{T}^{3}$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, finance, stochastic-differential-equations

Given a Black-Scholes Model and a derivative with payoff $S_{T}^{3}$ at time $T$. Check that the value of that derivative at time t is $V_{t} = g(t, T)S_{t}^{3}$, where $g(t, T)$ has to be determined.

I know the value of a derivative given its payoff can be written as $V_{t} = e^{-r(T-t)}  E[X|F_{t}]$, where X is the payoff $S_{T}^{3}$, but I do not know how to follow from here.

Edit: First, define $V_{t} = F(t, S_{t})$, where
$$F(t, S_{t}) = e^{-r(T-t)} E[(f(Se^{(T-t)(r-\sigma^{2}/2) + \sigma \sqrt{T - t} Z}$$ where $Z$ is a $N(0, 1)$. Then $V_{t} = e^{-r(T-t)} E[(Se^{(T-t)(r-\sigma^{2}/2) + \sigma \sqrt{T - t} Z})^{3}]$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thanks! I am familiar with tex writing, but that will be helpful since I know nothing about how this site works. From now on, I will try to be more specific.

Comment: A next step in your attempt could be to compute $E(S_T^3|F_t)$

Comment: Here is a try, though I am not sure if it is right. First, define $V_{t} = F(t, S_{t})$, where $F(t, S_{t}) =  e^{-r(T-t)} E[(f(Se^{(T-t)(r-\sigma^{2}/2) + \sigma \sqrt{T - t} Z}$, where Z is a N(0, 1). Then $V_{t} =  e^{-r(T-t)} E[(Se^{(T-t)(r-\sigma^{2}/2) + \sigma \sqrt{T - t} Z})^{3}$. From here, I am not sure about how should I compute the integral.

Comment: Please update your post with this attempt. Consider distributing the exponent into the $\exp (\cdots )$ term.

Comment: Following your indications I got: $V(t,S) = e^{-r(T-t)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} S_{T}^3 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{3r(T-t)-3\sigma^{2}/2 + 3\sigma \sqrt{T - t} z - z^{2}/2} dz$.

Then $V(t,S) = e^{2r(T-t)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} S_{T}^3 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-3\sigma^{2}/2 + 3\sigma \sqrt{T - t} z - z^{2}/2} dz$.

I tried to factorize the exponent, but there was no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the risk-neutral measure in the Black-Scholes model, the stock satisfies the SDE: $$dS_t = r S_t dt + \sigma S_t dB_t$$
whose solution is $S_t = S_0 \exp \left( (r - \sigma^2 / 2)t + \sigma B_t \right)$. The value of this derivative instrument is:
$$\begin{align*}
V(t,x) &= e^{-r(T-t)} \mathbb{E}\left[ S_T^3 \, | \, S_t = x\right] \\
&= e^{-r(T-t)} \mathbb{E}\left[ x^3 \exp \left( 3(r - \sigma^2 / 2)(T-t) + 3\sigma (B_T - B_t)  \right) \right] \\
&= e^{-r(T-t)} x^3 \exp \left( 3(r - \sigma^2 / 2)(T-t) \right) \mathbb{E}(\exp (3\sigma (B_T - B_t))) \\
&= e^{-r(T-t)} x^3 \exp \left( 3(r - \sigma^2 / 2)(T-t) \right) e^{\frac{9}{2} \sigma^2 (T-t)}
\end{align*}$$
where in the last line we used the fact that for $X \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$, we have $E{e^{X}} = e^{\frac{\sigma^2}{2}}$. Thus, $V$ is of the required form.